Is the "which" here grammartically correct?
The RNA techniques have strongly suggested that although the true bacteria indeed form a large coherent group, certain ______ are also prokaryotes and which resemble true bacteria, represent a distinct evolutionary branch that far antedates the common ancestor of all true bacteria.
Which choice completes the text so it conforms to the conventions of standard English?
(A) other bacteria the archaebacteria which
(B) other bacteria the archaebacteria, which
(C) other bacteria, the archaebacteria which
(D) other bacteria, the archaebacteria, which
I'm thinking D should be correct, but not really sure also. Can anyone shed a light?

What are you actually asking? The "which" is present in all four answers, so it's clearly intended here. The second "which" is optional, but correct. As for which answer out of the four is correct, note that "the archaebacteria" is a parenthesis.

It is an appositional structure and the second element is typically set off, as Maciej says, with commas:  ... certain other bacteria, the archaebacteria, ....  Since we have and later ("and which resemble") you have coordinated clauses, so you need two relative clauses headed by which.

The RNA techniques have strongly suggested that although the true bacteria indeed form a large coherent group, certain other bacteria, the archaebacteria, which are also prokaryotes and which resemble true bacteria, represent a distinct evolutionary branch that far antedates the common ancestor of all true bacteria.
The reason for the and-coordination of two separate relative clauses (the repetition of "which")  is that  the following single clause with coordinated predicates:

... which are also prokaryotes and resemble true bacteria...

might be understood to imply that resembling true bacteria is a feature of all prokaryotes, which is not the case.  Those two traits are features of archaebacteria, not of all prokaryotes.
For a similar inference drawn from coordination with and, compare:

... who are also Americans and love hamburgers

Therefore, being a prokaryotes is presented in its own relative clause and resembling true bacteria is presented in its its own relative clause.
See this example:

Let me mention now a further type of pathological change which I have described in a recent number of Endocrinology and which I have termed diffuse adenomatosis of the thyroid.

Goetsch, Emil. "The Diagnosis and Treatment of Hyperthyroidism" in International Record of Medicine and General Practice Clinics
edited by Edward Swift Dunster,  and others (March, 1921).

Let me mention now a further type of pathological change which I have described in a recent number of Endocrinology and I have termed it diffuse adenomatosis of the thyroid.

@gomadeng  What is the point you are making? I don't find your sentence to be an improvement over the original.

I upvoted your answer. 'and' is great.

Let us all praise "and".


(C)
Certain  other bacteria , the archaebacteria which are also prokaryotes and which resemble true bacteria , represent a distinct evolutionary branch that far antedates the common ancestor of all true bacteria.


(D) Certain  other bacteria , the archaebacteria , which are also prokaryotes and which resemble true bacteria , represent a distinct evolutionary branch that far antedates the common ancestor of all true bacteria.

Your which in italic type is grammatically wrong.
A relative pronoun already includes 'conjunctional function'. You don't need 'which' after 'and'.
With the "and which" being grammatically right, the (D) is wrong.
Because the relationship between the archaebacteria and prokaryotes is so strong and is in close connection: they interrelate with each other.
Your question seems like you asked about the "continuative" usage of relative pronouns. The continuative usage is used mainly to provide additional information. In other words, it is optional.
If the antecedent is intimately related to the following relative clause, then you should use the restrictive usage which means 'without comma'

thanks, i don't understand your answer tbh. So, if I read it correctly then no option is correct?

(C) is correct.

"which ..... and which...." is not grammatically wrong.  The two relative clauses are coordinated, permitting repetition of which. I could cite many examples, but here's one: https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Emigrant_s_Guide_to_Oregon_and_Calif/9I6JDZw_17YC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22and+which%22&pg=PA38&printsec=frontcover    Here's another: https://www.google.com/books/edition/College_and_University_Facilities_Survey/fbXoAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22and+which%22&pg=PA545&printsec=frontcover

And another: https://www.google.com/books/edition/International_Record_of_Medicine_and_Gen/42I5AQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22and+which%22&pg=PA379&printsec=frontcover
